# Can't get fancybox to pop out a window and play my youtube video

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, fancybox

I'm having issues getting fancybox-rails to work in my app.

My view

```
= link_to "http://www.youtube.com/embed/lGOkgbdGqKs", class: "fancybox fancybox.iframe { width:850, height:556 }"
```

Coffee Script

```
(document).ready ->
  $(".fancybox").fancybox()
```

application.css.sass

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require fancybox
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

The link is available, but I cannot make it pop up when i click it. Not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: Is there any output in the firebug console?

Comment: could you post the rendered html? at the end is what it matters

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problem. I was not giving an image or verbiage for my fancybox link. I was just inserting the URL and expecting it to figure out the name of the link.

I changed my link to:

```
= link_to "Video", "http://www.youtube.com/embed/lGOkgbdGqKs", class: "fancybox fancybox.iframe { width:850, height:556 }"
```

and it worked as expected